# NSString fails, app crashes trying to NSLog the NSError

Tags: objective-c, uikit, nsstring, nslog, nserror

What it says on the tin. All I want to do is save an NSString to a .txt file in my Documents directory so it can be accessed by the user. This is called in applicationWillTerminate:

```
NSError* err;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// the path to write file
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TheFile.txt"];
BOOL success = [[textView text] writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
if (!success) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", err, [err userInfo]);
}
```

In my case, success comes back as NO, and my app crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) on the NSLog line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `textView` (or `[textView text]`) is nil, `success` will be `NO` but `err` will be uninitialized. That's the only possible way to crash here.

Try setting `NSError* err = nil;`

Comment: Thanks! It was a combination of a null text view, and an uninitialized NSError.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be checking the `error` object, not the `success` boolean value. After all - that's why you're passing it's address for the write operation.

```
if (error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);
}
```

Also you may want to check that `[textView text]` does not return `nil` and if `textView` isn't `nil` itself.